# Styling the CSS of the drop-down list of select menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code for select-menu like this.

```
<select class="custom-select">
    <option value="">Select from the list</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I want to style the drop-down like the following:
[image]

I am wondering how can I achieve this with only CSS.
NOTE: I am using bootstrap select-menu.

Comment: You should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Styling_web_forms

Comment: Is it important to use select and options instead of div and links?

Comment: @olegoriginal Not necessary. But I want the same functionality of a select-menu like selecting default value (selected), etc. If there is any other simple way to style let me know.